# PowerShell keeps printing "doskey ..."

Tags: windows, powershell

I started working on my old computer again (hadn't touched it in two years) and while using PowerShell in Windows I noticed that it kept printing 'doskey make=mingw32-make.exe' every now and then. I remember I had some issues back then with make, so this might have been something I accidentally did. I would like to remove it, but I can't seem to get it right.

Example of the problem when booting Visual Studio Code:

[image: example of the problem when booting Visual Studio Code]

Comment: probably you ran it in the prompt. Can you show the result of `(Get-Command prompt).definition`?

Comment: @phuclv sorry for the delayed answer. Here's the result: 


"PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";
# .Link
# https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=225750
# .ExternalHelp System.Management.Automation.dll-help.xml

Comment: so the prompt is still normal. Do you see that behavior after each command, or only once every time you start powershell?

Comment: @phuclv
It doesn't appear when I start powershell, but it also doesn't appear for every command. Examples of when this behavior appears: when I open Visual Studio Code via the powershell (as the image above shows) or when I run a gradle project (https://imgur.com/a/pa5rodH)